# Is it ok to indicate in good faith a very approximate departure date, expected length of trip and list of countries when applying for reentry permit?

Tags: usa, resident-permit

Is it ok to indicate in good faith a very approximate date of departure, expected length of trip and list of countries when completing [Form I-131, Application for Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/i-131) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200823021419/https://www.uscis.gov/i-131)) when applying for a reentry permit? E.g., indicating 200 days but instead staying outside the US just for 50 days, or vice versa, and/or indicating countries A and B but instead going to countries X, Y and Z.

I don't see anything mentioned in the  [Instructions for Application for Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-131instr.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200823021430/https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-131instr.pdf)).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and I believe you can also write "Unknown" or "TBD" if you don't have any specific plans in mind.

Comment: This is a reasonable approach. Still, how do you know this, and what is behind "I believe?"